# Weird Behavior In MacOSX File Find

Tags: macos, mac, search, finder

I have these two searches. Why do they return different file sets? The shorter one seems to not return files that fit the requirement to contain "dona", but not contain "sams" or "mart".

[image: None-Any]

[image: None]

Comment: My boolean logic is terrible, but I think it's…1st is doing 'dona NOT (sams OR mart)' 2nd is 'dona NOT (sams AND mart)' so the first will reject if either sams or mart is found, the second will only reject if both are found.

Comment: The #CF file in the first shot is a file that has "dona" in it, does not have "sams" and does not have "mart". Seems like it satisfies both, but gets excluded in the second search?

Comment: Actually, seems like its "dona AND NOT (sams OR mart)" vs "dona NOT (sams OR mart)". The expression "dona NOT (sams AND mart)" gives me a different list.

Comment: you can't have 'AND NOT'… it's AND, OR, NOT or XOR [the last one just confuses the hell out of me] It would probably be much better explained by someone who does grok it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations for … ermm… absolutely no help at all ;-)